# Are there any Java Profilers which one can get with an MSDN membership?

Tags: java, optimization, jakarta-ee, profiler, msdn

Are there any Java Profilers one can get with an MSDN membership?  I would like a Profiler that can intergrate with WebSphere 6.1.

Grae

Comment: @Grae: I've updated the question with that edit (and removed my question comment). Good luck. (I don't know of any, and Microsoft isn't exactly big on Java, but that doesn't mean there *aren't* any.)

Comment: Why one from MSDN? The 1.6 JDK contains visual vm which has a profiler.

Comment: @Kaj I want something nicer. Basically, I have an MSDN subscription, so I would like to get a commercial version, for free. I know there free versions, but I trying to find a fancier one for free.

Comment: @Grae, define fancier (or ask MS)

Comment: @bestsss I just want a commercial profiler for free basically.  If there is an mircosoft product, I can get it for free through my company.

Comment: @Grae: your assumption that commercial products are necessarily "fancier" than free ones is... dubious.

Comment: @Grae, I guess you can donate money to some of the projects if you wish to feel it commercial, even java has a version called "java for business".why microsoft would have a java profiler on their own is beyond me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely MS would develop a profiler for the competitors platform don't you think?

If you wanted a .Net profiler that integrated with BizTalk you might have a chance with MSDN, but even then, I don't know of any free commercial profiler included in MSDN that is not free anyway (without MSDN).

For Java and Websphere, try some competitors like IBM, Sun, Oracle or Novell (I'm not up to date in the java world but those companies float to the top of my mind in this regard).